# React Navigation back to initial view after redux state change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I have connected my root view using one property of the redux state. Whenever i change that propery within the app using an action the StackNavigation resets and go back to its initial state. What i am missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are keeping the state immutable in your reducer?

Comment: yes im just changing from true to false one property of the state in the reducer

Comment: Its like when redux rerenders the view the navigation resets to initial state

Comment: You will have to provide code for investigating more into it.